# Validation library for python, pyside, qt desktop application

Tags: python, validation, desktop-application, pyside

I am developing a desktop application using Qt (Pyside) and Python.

Is there any library to validate all form fields at once on save button click? Please suggest if any.

Comment: Fields? What do you mean? Text input controls or what?

Comment: @reclosedev  yes, To validate text input, combo box, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for [QValidator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvalidator.html) and its sublcasses  `QDoubleValidator`, `QIntValidator`, and `QRegExpValidator`.

There is usage example [Line Edits Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-lineedits-example.html)